# Timed, looping text output on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, for-loop

I'm creating an app that displays a random word (a key from an NSDictionary) in a UILabel and a list of associated words (an NSArray that is the displayed key's value) in another UILabel when the user pushes a button. For example: if the user pushes the button, the main word might be "Cat" and the list would be something like "lion", "snow leopard", "tiger".

I'd like to loop the text output so that the user pushes the button once, gets a word and a list, there's a timed pause, and then the word and list refresh. Here's the method I have so far:

```
- (IBAction)changeWord:(UIButton*)sender {
        //next line displays the randomly selected NSDictionary key, such as "Cat" in a label
        self.label.text = [self.dictionary selectKey];
        //next two lines displays the value associated with the selected key (an array), such as "lion", "snow leopard", "tiger" in another label
        NSString *labelText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [self.dictionary selectList]];
        self.listLabel.text = labelText;
       }
```

That obviously doesn't loop and simply displays new output for both labels whenever the button is pressed. I thought that creating a for loop that loops as many times as there are dictionary keys would solve half of the problem:

```
- (IBAction)changeWord:(UIButton*)sender {

    //next line counts the keys in the NSDictionary
    NSInteger numberOfKeys = [self.dictionary CountKeys];
   for( int index = 0; index < numberOfKeys; index++ ) 
   {
    self.label.text = [self.dictionary selectKey];
    NSString *labelText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [self.dictionary selectList]];
    self.listLabel.text = labelText;
   //need some type of timer here! 
   }
```

But I need some type of timer that will pause the display at a regular interval before its refreshed. That's where I'm stuck!

Does anyone have any pointers?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method [`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay\]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-performSelector_withObject_afterDelay_) of NSObject:

```
- (IBAction)changeWord:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [self changeWord];
}

- (void)changeWord
{
    if (musicStopped) return;

    //next line displays the randomly selected NSDictionary key, such as "Cat" in a label
    self.label.text = [self.dictionary selectKey];
    //next two lines displays the value associated with the selected key (an array), such as "lion", "snow leopard", "tiger" in another label
    NSString *labelText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [self.dictionary selectList]];
    self.listLabel.text = labelText;

    // Add this line
    [self performSelector:@selector(changeWord) withObject:nil afterDelay:30.0];
}
```

Comment: +1, you were faster: But i think Orpheus wants to display the word immediately after button click and the list associated to it some time later...

Comment: @rokjarc - Probably, I just assumed he wants to repeat the code inside his for loop.

Comment: @rokjarc - Actually he says: *"... gets a word and a list, there's a timed pause, and then the word and list refresh."*. I guess that means he wants to refresh both.

Comment: Yes, i'm just looking at it and i'm not exactly sure :) he did say loop, you're right on that.

Comment: One last question: How should I be declaring `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`? I'm getting an error saying that my view controller's @interface doesn't declare it..

Comment: @OrpheusMercury - That method is already [there](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-performSelector_withObject_afterDelay_). You don't have to declare or implement it.

Comment: @sch I fixed an error that I'd made and now it works.  Now I just have to figure out how to stop the loop :) Thanks again!

Comment: Don't call `performSelector` when you want to stop the loop. If you need more help, you should explain when you want it to stop.

Comment: If that's too complex and requires too detailed an answer, then is there a way to stop the loop when the keys are exhausted?

Comment: I've already updated my answer to make the loop stop. If that isn't what you are looking for, try posting another question and explain the problem better.